# How simplify PHP function with array key-values?

Tags: php, arrays

This  is my php function to change month names from english to other languages and this function is working fine.

```
function _ld($sqldate, $lang){
    if(!$sqldate) $sqldate=date("Y-m-d");
    $phpdate = strtotime( $sqldate );
    $phpdate = date( 'd M Y', $phpdate );
    $eng = array("Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec");
    $kan   = array("ಜನವರಿ", "ಫೆಬ್ರವರಿ", "ಮಾರ್ಚ್","ಏಪ್ರಿಲ್", "ಮೇ", "ಜೂನ್","ಜುಲೈ", "ಆಗಸ್ಟ್", "ಸೆಪ್ಟೆಂಬರ್","ಅಕ್ಟೋಬರ್", "ನವಂಬರ್", "ಡಿಸೆಂಬರ್");
    $hin = array("जनवरी", "फ़रवरी", "मार्च","अप्रैल","मई","जून","जुलाई","आगस्त","सितम्बर","अकतूबर","नवेम्बर","दिसम्बर");
    switch ($lang) {
        case "kan" :
            $to = $kan;
            break;
        case "eng" :
            $to = $eng;
            break;
        case "hin" :
            $to = $hin;
            break;
        default :
            $to = $kan;
    }
    return str_replace($eng, $to, $phpdate);    
}

echo _ld();
```

Now I want to simplify this function by adding languages to `array (key=>values)`. Is this possible? If yes, how?

Please help me.

Comment: What's wrong with your current implementation. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @paullb As I said, this is working fine. But I want to learn is this possible to add `language variables` to a `single array with key=>values` and use it?

Comment: Please paste your desire output.

Comment: @HarshBarach The output is coming ok, say `echo _ld("2017-01-29","kan");` echoes `29 ಜನವರಿ 2017`. I want know how to put all languages to a single array like `$languages = array("Jan"=>array("Jan","ಜನವರಿ","जनवरी"),"Feb"=>array("Feb","ಫೆಬ್ರವರಿ","फरवरी"),...);` and process this according to `$lang` parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt: https://repl.it/GbwN/4
So it took me a while to format the array correctly (a ton of one-by-one copy pasting).

We store the month at `$month` and use it to iterate through our `$months`'s keys.
Removed your `$eng` array because it felt redundant.
`str_replace` now replaces `string` instead of `Array`.

Take note that `$lang = 0` is for `kan` while `$lang = 1` is for `hin`.

```
function _ld($sqldate, $lang){
  if(!$sqldate) $sqldate=date("Y-m-d");
  $phpdate = strtotime( $sqldate );
  $month = date( 'M', $phpdate );
  $phpdate = date( 'd M Y', $phpdate );

  $months = array(
    "Jan" => array("ಜನವರಿ", "जनवरी"),
    "Feb" => array("ಫೆಬ್ರವರಿ", "फ़रवरी"),
    "Mar" => array("ಮಾರ್ಚ್", "मार्च"),
    "Apr" => array("ಏಪ್ರಿಲ್", "अप्रैल"),
    "May" => array("ಮೇ", "मई"), 
    "Jun" => array("ಜೂನ್", "जून"),
    "Jul" => array("ಜುಲೈ", "जुलाई"),
    "Aug" => array("ಆಗಸ್ಟ್", "आगस्त"),
    "Sep" => array("ಸೆಪ್ಟೆಂಬರ್", "सितम्बर"),
    "Oct" => array("ಅಕ್ಟೋಬರ್", "अकतूबर"), 
    "Nov" => array("ನವಂಬರ್", "नवेम्बर"),
    "Dec" => array("ಡಿಸೆಂಬರ್", "दिसम्बर")
  );

  switch ($lang) {
    case "eng" :
      return $phpdate;
      break;
    case "kan" :
      $lang = 0;  
      break;
    case "hin" :
      $lang = 1;  
      break;
    default :
      $lang = 0;
  }    

  return str_replace($month, $months[$month][$lang], $phpdate);
}

echo _ld("2017-02-29","hin");
```

You could add keys to each month's language like:

> "Jan" => array("kan" => "ಜನವರಿ", "hin" => "जनवरी")

and change `$lang = 0` to `$lang = "kan"` to specify which array item we want to get.
I avoided this as I prefer not having the same thing repeated over and over again in my code.

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling to implement arrays in this function.